# mb_eregi error - need advice on how to solve

Tags: php

```
function encoded_header($raw) 
{
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');

    if ( mb_eregi('[^][<>a-z0-9 _".()/;,:+@|-]', $raw)  ) 
    {
        $chunks = str_split($raw,  20 );
        $encoded = array();

        foreach ( $chunks as $chunk ) 
        {
            array_push($encoded,  base64_encode( $chunk )  );
        }

        return '=?utf-8?B?' . implode('?==?utf-8?B?', $encoded) . '?=';
    } 
    else 
    {
        return $raw;
    }
}
```

The above function, when called, gives me:

```
Error: [2] - mb_eregi() [function.mb-eregi0]: mbregex compile err: premature end of char-class
```

We recently updated our php to version 5.3.3 and we encounter this error. Our previous version 5.0.2 worked fine.
I searched google but did not come up with anything useful. Anyone got any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Comment: use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and don't forget the `u` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Answer (score 4):

`mb_eregi()` is depreciated in version 5.3

so user `preg_match();`

try this:

```
preg_match('/[^][<>a-z0-9 _".()\;,:+@|-]/i', $row);
```

Comment: Didn't new mb_eregu was depreciated. According to php.net: PHP 4 >= 4.2.0, PHP 5 (without the classic red box of alert when sometihng is no longer suppoted).<br>
Anyway, your suggestion works. Thank you!

Comment: most of ereg() is depreciated as i know

Comment: even i also got this type of problem in past so